# Are there any languages with words for negative powers of 10 like Japanese?

Tags: list-of-languages, numbers

In Japanese they use 分, 厘, 毛, 糸, 忽, 微, 繊, 沙, 塵, 埃 for negative powers of 10 from 10<sup>-1</sup> to 10<sup>-10</sup> respectively

[image: Old system]

There's also another system with a little bit different value range

[image: New system]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals#Powers_of_10

Do any other languages have words similar to this?

Comment: English has a limited sense of this, with "percent (%)" for 10^-2 and the exceeding rare "permille (‰)" and "permyriad (‱)" for 10^-3 and 10^-4 respectively.

Comment: @MarkBeadles the difference in Japanese is that they can be used to say decimal numbers like 0.2589

Comment: I guess English can do this, somewhat awkwardly (0.2589 = 2589 ten-thousandths). I’m excited to learn this about Japanese, thanks.

Comment: Tenth, hundredth, thousandth?

Comment: Yes, I expect most metric countries will have something like Portuguese *décimo, centésimo, milésimo, milionésimo* etc.; but we don't normally use it for mixed naming. So for example 0.008 is referred to as *oito milésimos* (eight *milésimos*), but 0.258 won't normally be read as "two *décimos*, five *centésimos* eight *milésimos*" or "two-hundred fifth eight *milésimos*" (unless in certain contexts like e.g. a car race where "*milésimos* of a second" is the standard unit of measure).

Comment: If you merely said 一分 *ichi-bu*, people would not automatically assume 1/100th in general contexts, they would assume 1 part. Similarly obscure words probably exist in many languages.